# How to check whetherpop up blocker is turned ON or not in a browser using Code ?

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow

How to check whether pop up blocker is turned ON or not in a browser using java or Java script Code ?

```
function check ()
{
    document.login.action= url+"test.jsp";
    document.login.submit();
}
```

I will call this function on click of submit button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
var myWindow = window.open (url);

if (if (myWindow == null || typeof(myWindow )=='undefined'))
{
     // popup blocker is enabled
}
else
{
     myWindow.close();
}
```

Comment: ya thanks. it will work if i use window.open() but if i use post method to navigate page then how to check it ..?

Comment: function Validate()
{   
          
        document.frmlogin.action= url+"test.jsp";
        document.frmlogin.submit();
  
}

Comment: My only suggestion would be to check it on you landing page of your site and store the value of whether there is a popup blocker enabled for the rest of the session. I have not seen your method of navigating pages before so I cant comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `window.open()` to open the popup, check for the return value.
According to the MDC doc center (a good javascript reference) the return value is null if opening the window didn't succeed for whatever reason.

```
var windowReference = window.open(url);
```

See the [documentation on window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) here.